# Why Jasper Reports shows empty report in server, but generates correctly in jasper studio

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I am using Jasper Studio 6.6.0 and Jasper server 7.1.

I have created a simple report with an image from a specified URL.

It generates correctly in Jasper Studio, but in the server it shows empty.

Please refer images attached:

Server Screenshot
[image: server screenshot]
Jasper Screenshot
[image: jaspersoft screenshot]

Comment: It seems like you don't provide any data source or the data source is empty.

Comment: I am not using any data source. I just want to load an image from url provided. (No db connection required)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to show something in the JasperReport without data source or with empty data source then you have two options:

**1)** Set the **When No Data Type** property on **All Section No Detail** option in the Jasper Studio:
[image: When No Data Type]

In JRXML it can be done by setting `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"` attribute on the root `<jasperReport>` element.

**2)** Or you can move content you want to show when there is no data into **No Data** band of the report:
[image: No Data Band]

In JRXML it it can be done by adding of this:

```
<noData>
    <band height="110">
        <image>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="240" height="110" uuid="d4b9e59b-896e-4881-92a2-c6707c975312"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://my.image.url/getImage?name=penguin"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</noData>
```

---

JasperReport renders blank page when there are no data as a default and JasperServer shows *The report is empty*, so select from above options one you prefer to be able to show the image you want.

Comment: Now jasper server shows a blank report instead of "The report is empty". But it generates correct report for texts and all (without data)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you comment well - you mean that when you use `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"` or `<noData>` then texts are showing but image not?

Comment: Yes .  When I use whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" or <noData> , texts labels or static texts are showing, but image field is blank. (I'm trying to capture image from url for eg: http://example.com/test.jpg , If I try to capture image from local system or workspace it works fine. In case of url im facing this issue.) Also in Jasper Soft it works fine, But If I publish the report to Jasper Server , it shows blank

Comment: Then there must be problem with the image itself, it means next problem. You use URL, file path, image bytes, ...?

Comment: Got solution. Problem was with file name. File name had special characters. Now its working fine after i changed file name in url.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do not have the empty page when no data source is provided, is to trick jasper to think there is a data source:

1) Define an Data Adapter (a simple .xml file) and put it in reports folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><emptyDataAdapter class="net.sf.jasperreports.data.empty.EmptyDataAdapterImpl"><name>Data Adapter fake</name><recordCount>1</recordCount></emptyDataAdapter>
```

2) Link it into the main report:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="repor" language="javascript" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="c0eee90e-1b1a-4f34-ad99-1112847752de">
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="EmptyDataAdapter.xml"/>
```

prefix "repo:" to the value of the property for the data adapter, if the xml is deployed on jasper server.

The attribute "whenNoDataType" will be ignored.

Other details [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-deploy-and-use-data-adapter-jasperreports-server-v56).