# Jasper report export file pdf blank?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i use library jasper report to export file pdf, result is file pdf blank through file jrxml simple hello world. This is my code generator PDF:

```
@Override
public byte[] generatePDFReport(String inputFileName, Map<String, Object> params, JRDataSource dataSource) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    JasperReport jasperReport = null;
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        // Check if a compiled report exists
        if (storageService.jasperFileExists(inputFileName)) {
            jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(storageService.loadJasperFile(inputFileName));
        }
        // Compile report from source and save
        else {
            String jrxml = storageService.loadJrxmlFile(inputFileName);
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxml);
            // Save compiled report. Compiled report is loaded next time
            JRSaver.saveObject(jasperReport, storageService.loadJasperFile(inputFileName));
        }
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
        // return the PDF in bytes
        bytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
    } catch (JRException | IOException e) {
        log.error("Encountered error when loading jasper file", e);
    }
    return bytes;
}
@Override
public byte[] generatePDFReport(String inputFileName, Map<String, Object> params) {
    return generatePDFReport(inputFileName, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
}
```

And i check using oracle jdk:

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Can you tell my problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe your *jrxml* is wrong. Did you try to debug?

Comment: How to debug? I generate jrxml from jasper studio?

Comment: `I generate jrxml from jasper studio?` - I don't know. You should know better. `How to debug?` - You have Java code. Are you using some IDE?

Comment: @HậuChử Do you have any items in the `dataSource`? PDF can be blank simply because `dataSource` is empty -> nothing to iterate. You can add **No Data** band into the report to test it (explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52923506/9709361).